# method flow control

Tags: java

I have a form that give `Fname` and `Lname` and `Date` and a method to write this information to a file.

If `Fname` or `Lname` contain digit, the program should display an error message and not run all below statements ,(like write to file and generate random number and...), and not exit.
since i dont know how to do like this, in my code i write if Fname or Lname have digit, exit !

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)   {                                         
    try{
        setFName(jTextField1.getText());
        if(havedigit(getFName())==true) { 
            System.exit(1);
        }
        setLName(jTextField2.getText());
        if(havedigit(lastName)==true) {
            System.exit(1);
        }
        WriteToFile(getFName());
        WriteToFile(getLName());
        setDate(Integer.parseInt(jTextField3.getText()));
        WriteToFile(String.valueOf(getDate()));
        Random rnd1=new Random();
        Registration_Number=rnd1.nextInt(100);
        setRegNum(Registration_Number);
        WriteToFile(String.valueOf(getRegNum()));
        jLabel6.setText(String.valueOf(getRegNum()));
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        jLabel6.setText("Error!");
    }
}                                        

public boolean havedigit(String in){
    for(int i=0;i<in.length();i++){
        if(Character.isDigit(in.charAt(i)))  return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

please help!

Comment: `if (havedigit(getFName())==true)` Are you joking?

Comment: It's not _always_ the worst idea in the world to explicity compare to a boolean (although this usage is very unneccessary).  For example, my current team prefers not to use the `!` operator, but to use `someBool == false` for readability.

Comment: @jahroy Nice trick with readability

Comment: @mishadoff - I personally don't love the rule (I prefer using short variable names to make the `!` easier to see), but I understand the rationale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)   {                                         

    try{
        setFName(jTextField1.getText());
        setLName(jTextField2.getText());
        boolean firstNameHasDigit = havedigit(getFName());
        boolean lastNameHasDigit = havedigit(getLName());
        if (firstNameHasDigit || lastNameHasDigit) {
            jLabel6.setText("Names cannot contain digits");
        }
        else {
            WriteToFile(getFName());
            WriteToFile(getLName());
            setDate(Integer.parseInt(jTextField3.getText()));
            WriteToFile(String.valueOf(getDate()));
            Random rnd1=new Random();
            Registration_Number=rnd1.nextInt(100);
            setRegNum(Registration_Number);
            WriteToFile(String.valueOf(getRegNum()));
            jLabel6.setText(String.valueOf(getRegNum()));
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        jLabel6.setText("Error!");
    }
}                                        

public boolean havedigit(String in){
    for(int i=0;i<in.length();i++){
        if(Character.isDigit(in.charAt(i)))  return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: It was So useful. than you

Answer (score 2):

That's why you need **checked exceptions**. Just throw `SomeException` instead of `System.exit(1)` and process it properly in block:

```
catch (SomeException e){
    jLabel6.setText("Error!");
}
```

Don't think that catching all exceptions is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, try to stay away from using `System.exit()` in GUI-driven applications. It'll just make the whole program quit, leaving the user wondering what happened. `System.exit()` is usually better suited for command line applications that want to provide an exit code to the shell and it's a parallel to the [system exit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194959%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) calls available in most operating systems.

Try this:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)   {                                         
    try{
        setFName(jTextField1.getText());
        if(havedigit(getFName())) { 
            jLabel6.setText("First name error!");
            return;
        }
        setLName(jTextField2.getText());
        if(havedigit(lastName)) {
            jLabel6.setText("Last name error!");
            return;
        }
        WriteToFile(getFName());
        WriteToFile(getLName());
        setDate(Integer.parseInt(jTextField3.getText()));
        WriteToFile(String.valueOf(getDate()));
        Random rnd1=new Random();
        Registration_Number=rnd1.nextInt(100);
        setRegNum(Registration_Number);
        WriteToFile(String.valueOf(getRegNum()));
        jLabel6.setText(String.valueOf(getRegNum()));
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        jLabel6.setText("Error!");
    }
}
```

Comment: You do know that you can't terminate a swing program without calling System.exit :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(havedigit(getFName())==true) { 
        System.exit(1);
    }
    setLName(jTextField2.getText());
    if(havedigit(lastName)==true) {
        System.exit(1);
    }
```

should be

```
    if(havedigit(getFName())) { 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(.....);
        return; //get out of method, no need to continue
    }
    setLName(jTextField2.getText());
    if(havedigit(lastName)) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(.....);
        return; //get out of method, no need to continue
    }
```

Search on Google about how to use JOptionPane.showMessageDialog.

Comment: It was So useful. than you

Comment: No problem, you can select it as an answer if it resolves your issue :)

Answer (score -1):

In your if statements, instead of

```
System.exit(1);
```

You should have something

```
throw new MyException("Error Text");
```

and then your catch should look like this:

```
catch(MyException e){
    jLabel6.setText(e.getMessage());
}
```

where MyException extends Exception.

Comment: Bad advice!!!  Don't throw `Exception`.  Choose an exception class that reflects the actual event that you are "signalling" ... or define a new exception class.  Throwing `Exception` makes it difficult for the handler to discriminate between different events.

Comment: Is this just bad practice or would this fail to fix his/her problem?

Comment: This does exactly what the OP asked for. It displays an error message and then doesn't run the rest of the code in the `try` block.

Comment: Yes! It does exactly what OP asks for ("If Fname or Lname contain digit, the program should display an error message and not run all below statements ,(like write to file and generate random number and...), and not exit.") I read through his entire post, came up with a solution that works, and posted it.  You've down-voted my answer and have openly spoken against it while admitting you don't even understand the question.  Can you please either delete your comments and remove your down-vote or explain why this doesn't work.

Comment: Throwing `java.lang.Exception` is very bad practice.  While you have since corrected this (though poorly ... because `MyException` is a most unhelpful name), I think a downvote is still warranted.  'Cos it is more than just a simple error ... it is recommending bad practice.  Just don't do it.